# Opacity bug on Maui

Tags: c#, xamarin, maui, .net-maui

guys!

I'm facing the following issue: the opacity insn't working on Frame and BoxView when running the app via Debug or Release. Once the app is loaded and something is changed in the xaml and the hot reload takes action, the opacity comes to life.

Steps to reproduce the issue:

Just create I Frame or BoxView with BackgroundColor and opacity. Run the app. Will see no opacity.

```
<VerticalStackLayout
        Spacing="25"
        Padding="30,0"
        VerticalOptions="Center">

        <Frame
            BackgroundColor="Blue"
            Opacity="0.5"/>
            
    </VerticalStackLayout>
```

The issue:

The Opacity is being ignored when the app starts.

I'm using VS 2022 17.3. I've created other Maui projects with real devices, emulators, VS 2022 preview 17.4 and got the same issue

Anybody else having this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: If this is a bug report, please go to the issue tracker for MAUI and file a report there: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues. Otherwise, it's unclear what your question here is.

Comment: I tried the code on my side, the opacity in frame works well on windows machine, but it can not work well on android device and emulators. Then I tried the the opacity in boxview and it works well on both sides and my VS version is 2022 17.3. I think the feature may not have been migrated yet. I will report the problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because StackOverflow isn't the Issue Tracker in github.

Comment: I am experiencing this with Rectangle.  If I update the opacity value during runtime it resolves. Annoying.

Comment: And as Ruslan advise, I use Border to make work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Look here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/frame?view=net-maui-7.0) and read the (!)Note

> The Frame class existed in Xamarin.Forms and is present in .NET MAUI for users who are migrating their apps from Xamarin.Forms to .NET MAUI. If you're building a new .NET MAUI app it's recommended to use Border instead, and to set shadows using the Shadow bindable property on VisualElement. For more information, see Border and Shadow.

solution: use Border instead of Frame

Comment: Border works. Thanks!